# Is MFC CListCtrl suitable if no image/icon is wanted in any column?

Tags: c++, mfc

The MFC CListCtrl is stressed that it can display small/large icons in various modes. I want to use the control in ReportView mode with **no icons whatsoever**.
In other words, I wish to display text in all columns.

Can I do that?
If no, what MFC control is suitable for this problem?
I am amazed that the general problem of displaying a grid with an arbitrary type in any column (or an arbitrary type in any row/column position).

I have considered a ListView but I dont think this is suitable for my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, which can already be concluded when looking at the available overloads of the [`InsertItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019#insertitem) method. The simplest overload doesn't require you to pass an image index:

```
int InsertItem(
    int nItem,
    LPCTSTR lpszItem);
```

Even when using the most sophisticated overload, you are not required to define an image index:

```
int InsertItem(const LVITEM* pItem);
```

To use the [`LVITEM::iImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taglvitema) member, you would have to include the `LVIF_IMAGE` flag in the `LVITEM::mask` member. Simply leave that flag alone, to insert an item without an icon.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the mfc clistview works without any icons in report mode. I use it like that, as a poor man's spreadsheet.